# Star schema role in the Pentaho Mondrian OLAP server

Tags: rdbms, olap, mondrian, star-schema

I'm trying to understand the OLAP paradigm.

More specifically I would like to do some OLAP queries on our 'OLTP' data using the Pentaho Mondrian OLAP server.

I have read the online documntation, but I don't understand the data flow being used by the Mondrian.

Do I need to transform our 'OLTP' data into a star schema, which then the Mondrian reads from and creates the OLAP cube and performs queries against? Or is the star schema build by the Mondrian itself for its internal purposes?

I would appreciate any help on this.